# injecting FacesContext into spring bean

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I have bean that i recently converted over from being a managed-bean to being a spring-bean.

Everything was ok until at some point the following method is called:

```
Exception e = (Exception) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get(
                    AbstractProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY);
```

At this point things blow up because `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` returns null.

is it possible to inject the faces context into my bean?

Comment: Just by way of background: if `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` returns null, then the call is likely being made outside the JSF lifecycle (either before the context has been initialized, after it has been destroyed, or on a different thread). `FacesContext` instances have a per-request scope held in a `ThreadLocal` variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is it possible to inject the faces context into my bean?

Not sure, but in this particular case it's not needed. The [`ExternalContext#getSessionMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSessionMap%28%29) is basically a facade to the attributes of [`HttpSession`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). To the point, you just need to grab the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) in your Spring bean somehow and then get the `HttpSession` from it by [`HttpServletRequest#getSession()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29). Then you can access the session attributes by [`HttpSession#getAttribute()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29).

I don't do Spring, but [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=get+httpservletrequest+in+spring+bean) learns me that you could obtain it as follows:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

Once done that, you can just do:

```
Exception e = (Exception) request.getSession().getAttribute(AbstractProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY);
```

Comment: what is your consulting rate? also, do you know how i can get managed beans, are they in the session?

Comment: On SO, I'm happy enough with a vote and a green mark. As to managed beans, they are stored as attributes of `HttpServletRequest` (request scope), `HttpSession` (session scope) and `ServletContext` (application scope) as well by their managed bean name as key. You know, JSF (and Spring) just runs on top of "raw" Servlet API.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the exact same problem today, so I wanted to post this answer for future reference.

FacesContext can be injected using:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{facesContext}")
FacesContext faces;
```

It works for spring beans too, provided Spring and JSF are integrated properly in the application.

Reference:

[Integrating Spring and JSF](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/)

[Injecting FacesContext](http://content.jsfcentral.com/c/journal_articles/view_article_content?groupId=35702&articleId=58321&version=1.7#.U1C4CPmSxIk)

Comment: Thank you! I've been working on this for 10 hours, and these two lines of code took care of it.